# Does WTL CWindowImpl compatible with CWnd?

Tags: sdl-2, wtl

i have simple video player.

https://github.com/sailfish009/sample_video

now i want to port it to windows template library 9.1.

Edit: solved, CWindowImpl's handler compatible with CWnd's.

```
//screen = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(this->m_hWnd); //HWND from CWnd previous working code
screen = SDL_CreateWindowFrom(m_hWndClient);   //HWND from CWindowImpl
```

Comment: solved! i made a mistake setting width and height. HWND from CWindowImpl and CWnd are same exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The question is asked incorrectly. You don't look for compatibility, you just look for a way to access `HWND` window handle.

No, the classes are not compatible and more to that they are different conceptually. In ATL/WTL `CWindowImpl` is a class that implements a window procedure. Such procedure is typically a static function, and the helper class does the job of "attaching" it to C++ class, connects it to specific thin window wrapper such as `CWindow`, offers easy way to connect message handlers etc. `m_hWndClient` is not even a member of `CWindowImpl` and belongs to WTL frame window related classes.